# Trouble with the Storage and Retrieve System

Tags: anylogic

Description of a Model :A week before i started Learning Anylogic  and Developing a WareHouse Model, which take Pallets from a Truck and unload it by unloaders and place it at someplace then Transferer will pick that pallets and then put it on a conveyor. At the end of the Conveyor the Forklifters will pick and place it in a storage area. After a delay then Forklifters will Retrieve it and place at somepoint then loaders will pick that up and loaded in to a RetailTruck.

1. Error: showing error in retrive system as
   root.retrieve: Cannot reach cell [Cell: [Storage: storage, Rack: 0, Bay: 1, Shelf: 0, Depth: 2]] to remove agent [150] from storage.
2. Error : If i increase the quantity of loaders and unloaders or incoming Trucks then i am getting an error as root.moveTo6.out
   this i dont have a screenshot to show it.

Can someone please Help me in this.

```
[Retrieve][1]
[TranspoterFleet][2]
[Storage][3]
[Logic][4]
[Error][5]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywphY.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASsnU.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CftFx.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEsBF.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmtRJ.png
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very specific questions on a problem, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. Your question is a generic “can someone help” question. This is too broad for SOF. I suggest you read up here to learn how to ask great questions here: Use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focused on AnyLogic: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow . Welcome again, we are all happy to help on specifics :) But treat us like very busy colleagues :)

Comment: Thank you for your response, Mr.Benjamin i consider your advice and try to implement it in the next question if that is to be posted. I have seen your Youtube video to solve the Runtime Errors(NullPointer And  Increase in Capacity). First, i used to get an error at MoveTo, after watching Your video i have increased the quantity of Resources.  But later Stuck with the Storage Error.  [Storage: storage, Rack: 0, Bay: 1, Shelf: 0, Depth: 2]...Anyhow i have attached the link to the screenshots of the code and error in the Main Question.

Comment: Suggest you simplify the model until the error goes away, then isolate what causes it. Very hard to help "blindly" here :)